# Android Studio is using Gradle cached version of React-Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have a forked version of React Native that lives in `node_modules`.

However, Android Studio is still using the React Native installation found in `~/.gradle/caches`. I know this because if I do an import like:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
```

and I command+click on the last part of it, the file it opens live in `~/.gradle/caches`, and it's a very old version of React Native (0.20.1)

If I delete the cache, and rebuild the project, the same version is downloaded automatically.

How can I get Android Studio to look in my `node_modules` directory and not the cached directory for React Native?

In settings.gradle:

```
...
include ':react-native-android'
project(':react-native-android').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
```

In app/build.gradle

```
...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':react-native-android')
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native'
}
```

In build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what helped:

```
./gradlew :ReactAndroid:assembleDebug
```

Then:

```
./gradlew :ReactAndroid:installArchives
```

Sources:

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/858

https://github.com/uk-ar/react-native/tree/master/ReactAndroid